# Aggregate query with where condition

Tags: mongodb, datetime, aggregation-framework

How could the following SQL query be converted for Mongo:

```sql
SELECT KeyID, SUM(Qty)
FROM Table
WHERE Date <= '1998-12-01'
```

Comment: How is the form of your collection?

Answer (score 58):

Something like:

```
db.myTable.aggregate([
  { $match: { mydate: { $lte: new Date('12/01/1998') } } },
  { $group: {
    _id: "$keyid",
    totalqty: { $sum: "$qty" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: For newbie: object contains $match must stay before $group, if not, an empty array will be returned

Answer (score 1):

Can use this -

```
db.schoolexamregistration.aggregate([
    { $match: {"exam_session_id":"1523850138707"} },{
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "student",
         localField: "nic_ppt",
         foreignField: "nic_ppt",
         as: "student_detail"
       }
    }
  ])
```

Comment: this answer solves completely different task. There is no sum aggregation and date compare at all in this query