# MongoDB: aggregation with if condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two mongo collection of documents (BlogPosts & UsersActivities), once blog post viewed or commented by user, a record is created in UsersActivities. Blog posts are classified by types (A, B, ...). UsersActivities.status is an enum["Viewed", "Commented"]

Collections with some dummy data:

```
BlogPosts: [
  { _postId: 1, content: "some text 1", type: 'A'},
  { _postId: 2, content: "some text 2", type: 'A'},
  { _postId: 3, content: "some text 3", type: 'A'},
  { _postId: 4, content: "some text 4", type: 'B'}
]

UsersActivities:[
  { _userId: 1, _postId: 1, status: "Viewed"},
  { _userId: 1, _postId: 1, status: "Commented"},
  { _userId: 1, _postId: 2, status: "Viewed"},
  { _userId: 1, _postId: 4, status: "Viewed"},
  { _userId: 2, _postId: 1, status: "Viewed"}
]
```

I am trying to write a query which will return a distinct list of all blog posts of type A, and with userId 1 status on each post (if post is viewed and commented, status should be "Commented". if no status found, status should be an empty string). The query result should looks like this:

```
[
  {_postId: 1, content: "some text 1", type: 'A', status: "Commented"},
  {_postId: 2, content: "some text 2", type: 'A', status: "Viewed"},
  {_postId: 3, content: "some text 3", type: 'A', status: ""}
]
```

This is the code I've wrote so far, but I got stuck and don't know how to proceed.

```
BlogPosts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      localField: "_postId",
      from: "UsersActivities",
      foreignField: "_postId",
      as: "UsersActivities",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      type: "A",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$UsersActivities",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "UsersActivities._userId": _userId,
        },
        {
          "UsersActivities._userId": null,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
])
```

Please advise, how can I achieve the required result

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294556/aggregate-query-with-where-condition

Comment: Since you are "joining" two collections, the aggregation should use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) stage which allows that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Project aggregation operator with **MongoDB** **switch** statement

```
{
    $project: {
        content: 1,
         ....
        {
            UsersActivities: {
                {
                    status: {
                        $switch: {
                            branches: [{
                                    case: {
                                        $eq: ['$UsersActivities.status', 'Commented']
                                    },
                                    then: '$UsersActivities.status'
                                },
                                {
                                    case: {
                                        $eq: ['$UsersActivities.status', 'Viewed']
                                    },
                                    then: '$UsersActivities.Viewed'
                                }
                            ],
                            default: ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```